# NullPointerException if I setOnClickListener for button from array

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I created array of buttons in a loop. It seems to work, but if I add `OnClickListener` to each button, I get a `NullPointerException`. How do I fix that?

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    fieldModel=new Field();
    buttons=new Button[10][10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            String buttonID = "button" + i + j;
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
            buttons[i][j] = ((Button) findViewById(resID));
            buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // <-- I get the exception here...
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    "some action"
        }
});
```

Comment: Are these buttons in Your layout.main_layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R.layout.main_layout, are there 100 buttons named 'button00' to 'button99'? if any one is missing, it will result in a null pointer at the line you have marked.

It would also be worth looking at using a GridView, or a RecyclerView with  GridLayoutManager, instead of adding the buttons manually - if it would suit your app.

Comment: Thanks! Button is missing, but i don't thought that it may cause error, because error appear on first button that exist.

Answer (score 0):

You get the exception because the id isn't contained by the activity layout. You have to add them first in the layout file if you want to match the Button object through findViewById or, if you have them already, make sure the Id you use in findViewById (resId) is correct.